# .NET Ignite cache expiry policy not working

Tags: outputcache, ignite

I am trying to set a global expiring policy to a Ignite cache but it doesn't work, all the entries are still there even after the timeout value.
This is how I am implementing it:

```
var igniteCache = this.igniteInstance.GetOrCreateCache<string, object>(configuraton);

var expiringTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
igniteCache.WithExpiryPolicy(new ExpiryPolicy(expiringTime, expiringTime, expiringTime));

igniteCache.Put(key, value);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithExpiryPolicy` returns a new cache instance, you should use it to insert entries with expiration:

```
var igniteCacheExpiry = igniteCache.WithExpiryPolicy(new ExpiryPolicy(expiringTime, expiringTime, expiringTime));

igniteCacheExpiry.Put(key, value)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this expiry policy valid for the entire cache or just the key/value entry?

Comment: Expiry policy has effect on all relevant operations of returned ICache instance. You can also set global expiry policy for a cache via `CacheConfiguration.ExpiryPolicyFactory`.